# Serialize Set of UUID using Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, uuid

I found that jackson comes equipped with a UUID serizlizer/deserializer that can be used like this:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {

    @JsonSerialize(using=UUIDSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using=UUDIDeserializer.class)
    private UUID myUUID;

}
```

And then using `ObjectMapper` on `MyClass` will correctly serialize/deserialize the `myUUID` field.

However, my class has a set of UUIDs that I want to serialize. I tried annotating the field the same way as above, but it complains that Set cannot be converted to UUID (as I  half expected).

I know I can create my own serializer/deserializers by extending `JsonSerializer`/`JsonDeserializer`, but this feels hacky. Is there another solution I can use? I also don't have the option to configure the `ObjectMapper` with my classes, since I don't have access to the `ObjectMapper`. I am using Amazon SWF and it automatically uses Jackson.

Comment: did you try `@JsonSerialize.contentUsing`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jackson should automatically use UUID serializers, deserializers, so your annotations should not be necessary.

But as to annotation usage, as suggested, (de)serializer for content (instead of value itself!) does need to use `contentUsing` property of the annotation -- otherwise Jackson will try to apply given (de)serializer directly for the value, with reported mismatch,