# spring framwork: UUID in @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring

Next example works fine:

```
@PostMapping("/test/{id}")
public ResponseEntity test(@PathVariable UUID id)
{
    System.out.println(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

but when I try to use UUID in RequestBody

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity test(@RequestBody TestDTO testDTO)
{
    System.out.println(testDTO.id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

then I get `null` in console

id field has UUID type

```
public class TestDTO {
    UUID id;
}
```

if replaced UUID by String, then code works fine.

my request look like this

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}' localhost:8080/test/test
```

how to fix it using UUID ?

Comment: Please try with modification: localhost:8080/api/test

It becomes:

curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":  "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}' localhost:8080/api/test

Comment: @NilanjanB my resource is also annotated as 'test', It's not routing problem, the endpoint is called and prints `null`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300625/serialize-set-of-uuid-using-jackson

Comment: @dehasi thanks, it`s works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add getter/setters of the `id` properties then you will get the value of it.

[here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not) I found one good demonstration about the JSON Marshalling

Answer (score 2):

Annotated with `@JsonDeserialize` field works fine:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

import java.util.UUID;

public class TestDTO {
    @JsonDeserialize
    UUID id;
}
```

UPD:

this solutions works too without annotations:

```
public class TestDTO {

    private UUID id;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: That or add a the getter/setter for the field. Default for jackson is to use properties (which are defined by getter/setters) instead of fields.