# JAX RS 2.0 Not Converting UUIDs

Tags: java, jax-rs, weblogic12c

I have been given an OpenAPI yaml file and have used the maven openapi generator plugin to turn this into Java.  This is being deployed to Weblogic 12.2.1.4 which should have Jersey 2.22 intalled.

This is largely working except for some UUID columns which are just coming through as null.

There is an API class

```
@Path("/jobtest")
public class JobTestAPI {
  @POST
  @Consumes({ "application/json" })
  public Response jobTestNotification(@Valid @NotNull JobTestNotification jobTetNotification) {
    return Response.ok().entity("OK").build();
  }
}
```

and a data class

```
@JsonTypeName ("JobTestNotification")
public class JobTestNotification {
  private @Valid UUID jobId;
  private @Valid Date jobTimestamp;
  private @Valid String jobDescription;

  @JsonProperty("jobId")
  @NotNull
  public UUID getJobId() {
    return jobId;
  }

  @JsonProperty("jobId")
  public void setJobId(UUID jobId) {
    this.jobId = jobId;
  }

  // Other getters / setters with same annotations
}
```

Sending

```
{
  "jobId": "abcdef12-abcd-ef12-1234-abcdef123456",
  "jobTimestamp": "2022-11-10T09:00:00.000Z",
  "jobDescription": "Some description"
}
```

I am getting a bad request and adding in an ExceptionMapper I see it is complaining that the UUID is null.   Indeed if I take out the `@Valid` annotation on the API method and print out the object I can see the other two values are there but the UUID field is null.

If I change the datatype of jobId to String it works.

My understanding is that as UUID implements a static `fromString` method there is no need for a custom converter (and indeed trying to implement one didn't seem to work).

Why are these fields not being mapped through (I have treble checked they are being passed with correct names and are definitely there)?    Other than just changing the values to String what can I do to get this work

Comment: "My understanding is that as UUID implements a static fromString method there is no need for a custom converter (and indeed trying to implement one didn't seem to work)." - that is not correct, as UUID is missing a constructor accepting a string and is not providing a Builder or something like this. A custom converter is required.

Comment: Ah I misread https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e2273 as UUIDs work fine if they are query parameters.   It is the JSON deserialization that isn't working here.   Not sure where to start without resorting to a complete manual deserializer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34300625/2587435

Comment: @PaulSamsotha as that says, Jackson should serialize / deserialize UUIDs automatically.    I tried adding `@JsonDeserialize` annotation (using both the Jackson class and a custom one I created) but it was never actually called and still had the same problem.   It must be down to how JAX-RS is interacting with Jackson in the background as I never get into calling the ObjectMapper directly.   It is a bit frustrating that  I need to deviate from the OpenApi yaml but it isn't too much trouble to just treat the UUIDs as strings (validated by a regexp)

Comment: Are you sure Jackson is the provider being used?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Bingo.   I was under the impression 12.2.1.4 had shifted to Jackson when it implemented Java EE7 compatibility.  The fact the Jackson annotations were there and it worked meant I didn't question it.    Taking the Jackson annotation out and it still works...    Looks like it is still using Moxy and I think 2.22.4 and whilst I haven't checked the exact timing looks like that is just before this was fixed https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=500139.   Thanks